# iOS crash when switching view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uialertview

I have a crash when switching between two view controllers.  Basically the layout goes like this
--> Swipe to the right to reveal the left menu view underneath the top View Controller
--> Upon launching the app will initially check for your authentication and a UIAlertView will show once it gets a response back from the server to identify that you are not authenticated.

If during the authentication piece I swipe to the right to reveal the left menu view controller underneath and then select it to launch a new view controller before the top view controller returns it will load my second view controller but then it will show the UIAlertView on that screen that was meant for the top view controller which has already been switched off of.  So when you click a button to dismiss that UIAlertView it crashes the app.  Here is the crash thread 0:

```
    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3bcc75b0 objc_msgSend + 16
    1   UIKit                           0x35f03c4c -[UIAlertView(Private) _buttonClicked:] + 292
    2   UIKit                           0x35e970c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68
    3   UIKit                           0x35e97072 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
    4   UIKit                           0x35e97050 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
    5   UIKit                           0x35e96906 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498
    6   UIKit                           0x35e96dfc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484
    7   UIKit                           0x35dbf5ec -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
    8   UIKit                           0x35dac7fc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
    9   UIKit                           0x35dac116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
    10  GraphicsServices                0x37ac45a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
    11  GraphicsServices                0x37ac41ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
    12  CoreFoundation                  0x33f79170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
    13  CoreFoundation                  0x33f79112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
    14  CoreFoundation                  0x33f77f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
    15  CoreFoundation                  0x33eeaeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
    16  CoreFoundation                  0x33eead44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
    17  GraphicsServices                0x37ac32e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
    18  UIKit                           0x35e002fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
    19  iShame                          0x000bbe90 main (main.m:16)
    20  libdyld.dylib                   0x3c103b1c start + 0
```

Here is my dealloc method on the top view controller which I would think would resolve the problem by setting them to nil in it:

```
    - (void)dealloc
    {
        noConnection = nil;
        userSetup = nil;
        userExist = nil;
        accountAlertView = nil;
        confirmed = nil;
        login = nil;

        if (_connection)
        {
            [_connection cancel];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Any direction on where to go with this would be much appreciated.  The only thing I can think of right now is basically disable the swipe action and menu button that reveals the menu until it receives the notification back from the server on the users authentication status.  Ideas please?

Potential Work Around:

```
    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [noConnection dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];// = nil;
        [userSetup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; //= nil;
        [userExist dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; //= nil;
        [accountAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; //= nil;
        [confirmed dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; //= nil;
        [login dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; //= nil;

        if (_connection)
        {
            [_connection cancel];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes the project is using ARC.

Comment: I edited my question, I think this might be at least a work around so it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. Disable the swipe action for the top view controller until you get the response from the server during the authentication. Enable the swipe action once based on the response.

Comment: I updated my post with what I think would be a better solution.  Basically in the dealloc method go ahead and just automatically acknowledge the notification if it does come back.  This way I don't have to lock up the apps functionality during the network calls.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the issue and I can no longer get it to crash.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [noConnection dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];// = nil;
    [userSetup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; //= nil;
    [userExist dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; //= nil;
    [accountAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; //= nil;
    [confirmed dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; //= nil;
    [login dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; //= nil;

    if (_connection)
    {
        [_connection cancel];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
}
```